# Switching Tab and reboot activity

Tags: android, tabs

I want to restart the activity when switch every time, 
One activity connects the network and uploads data.

If it displays data successfully, there is no need to restart the activity on tab change.

If it's not able to displays data unsuccessfully, I hope restart activity when switches tab every time and connect network to upload again.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this code

```
  productSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Products");
   Intent productsIntent = new Intent(this, ProductActivity.class);
            Bundle param = new Bundle();
            param.putInt("Categories", 0); //Your id
            param.putCharSequence("CategoryName", "No Category");
            productsIntent.putExtras(param);
            productSpec.setContent(productsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

// this is where we are Clear the current tab ..

Access the tabHost in different activity and do the same..

```
 Intent productsIntent = new Intent(context, ProductActivity.class);
                        Bundle param = new Bundle();
                        param.putInt("Categories", 1); //Your id
                        param.putCharSequence("CategoryName", categoryValues[position]);
                        productsIntent.putExtras(param);
                        MainTabActivity.productSpec.setContent(productsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                        MainTabActivity.tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
```

Comment: Please let me know , If you have any queries.??